# How to change MesiboProfile address?

Tags: mesibo

when using phone number as identifier/address in mesibo profile, there is case to change phone number like whatsapp/telegram.

How to achive that?, is mesibo support that case?, i didn't find any documentation tell about that

Comment: Profile is per address and hence address in the profile can not be changed. Can you describe what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: I want to add feature to let user change  their current phone number with other number rather than creating new profile @mesibo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, there is no direct way to change a user's address in mesibo since it can raise privacy concerns -- it could allow one user to access another's private messages and data.

The services like WhatsApp that you mentioned allow phone number changes via backup and restore (https://faq.whatsapp.com/553953002734024), while mesibo offers the same feature, it takes a more privacy-focused approach with extra validations.

Hence in your case, instead of direct address changes, you will need to create a new user account with the new phone number and link it to the old account.

This linking feature is normally used to allow users to log in from multiple devices and synchronization. But in this case, it enables syncing messages to the new account from the old account or allows the use of the existing database.

Please refer to the following documentation for more details on multi-device sync and backup/restore:

https://docs.mesibo.com/api/messaging/multi-device-login-and-synchronization/
https://docs.mesibo.com/api/initialization/backup-and-restore/